# Combobox in vuetify does not work like input

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

i am using vuetify and his component combobox for search action on website.
when i am typing something in combobox text value add in watcher only when event mouse exit, it does not good for me, because if user typed smthing in this field then clicked on button search nothing happening, only on second click search will work

```
                <v-combobox 

                dense 
                v-model="watcher"
                
                items="ItemsArray"
                item-text="ItemsArray.item_name" 
                label="item name" 
                
                />

<v-btn @click="Search">Search</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add ":" for the before items. such as,

```
<v-combobox 

                dense 
                v-model="watcher"
                
                :items="ItemsArray"
                :search-input.sync="search"
                item-text="ItemsArray.item_name" 
                label="item name" 
                
                />

<v-btn @click="Search">Search</v-btn>
```

Comment: thanks, its work, but instead 'search' i have added 'watcher' , ":" already added, just forgot to add in example